# Disable marker on certain points on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Hi my solution for this was:

```
data:{
     series:[
         {
            x: 1234,
            y: 45678,
           marker: {
               enabled: false,
               states:{
                  hover:{
                     enabled: false,
                  },
                  select:{
                     enabled: false,
                  }
               }
             }
        },
        .... //other data
  ]
```

}

But for the state hover still appears... :(

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/favio41/ertzq/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1610

**UPDATE:** The bug is fixed now. Make sure you are using latest version of Highcharts library.